# How to compare objects using lodash regardless on their order

Tags: javascript, lodash

I am trying to compare two objects using lodash like below. The problem is that it always returns false. I think that the issue is that the objects have different order of keys and values. I however couldn't find a solution on how to compare it regardless on the order.

**How to ignore the order and compare the two objects correctly?**

```
var obj1 = {                                                                                                                     
  event: 'pageInformation',                                                                                           
  page: { type: 'event', category: 'sportsbook' },                                                                     
  username: 'anonymous',                                                                                              
  pagePath: '/',                
  item: { name: 'Barcelona - Leganes', id: '123' },                                                           
  contest: { name: '1.Španielsko', id: 'MSK70' },                                                                     
  category: { name: 'Futbal', id: 'MSK3' },                                                                           
  teams: [                                                                                                            
    { id: 'barcelona', name: 'Barcelona' },                                                                           
    { id: 'leganes', name: 'Leganes' }                                                                                
  ]                                                                                                                   
}                                                                                                                     
var obj2 = {                                                                                                                     
  event: 'pageInformation',                                                                                           
  page: { type: 'event', category: 'sportsbook' },                                                                    
  username: 'anonymous',                                                                                              
  pagePath: '/',                
  category: { id: 'MSK3', name: 'Futbal' },                                                                           
  contest: { name: '1.Španielsko', id: 'MSK70' },                                                                     
  item: { id: '123', name: 'Barcelona - Leganes' },                                                           
  teams: [                                                                                                            
    { name: 'Barcelona', id: 'barcelona' },                                                                           
    { name: 'Leganes', id: 'leganes' }                                                                                
  ]                                                                                                                   
}         

function compareObjects(obj1, obj2){
 return _.isMatch(obj1, obj2);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the isEqual function which does a deep equal check (regardless of key order):

```
   _.isEqual(obj1, obj2)
```

See more here: https://lodash.com/docs/2.4.2#isEqual

Comment: tried that as well. But the value order matters as well I guess, still getting false.

Comment: Have you updated to the latest version of lodash?: https://github.com/lodash/lodash/issues/1758

Comment: sorry, there was also a missplelling in the two objects. isEqual is working perfectly.